# Cannot upgrade guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.8 => 7.7.1) when passing from 9.5.11 to 10.1.5

Tags: composer, upgrading, 10

I am trying to upgrade from Drupal 9.5.11 to 10.1.5.  I am also running PHP 8.1.14.

[root@ip-172-31-13-94 demo9]# **composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update**

./composer.json has been updated

[root@ip-172-31-13-94 demo9]# **composer require 'drush/drush:^12' --no-update**

./composer.json has been updated

[root@ip-172-31-13-94 demo9]# **composer update**

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.0.11] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.5.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-beta1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.5.1 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta6 requires doctrine/common dev-master#a45d110f71c323e29f41eb0696fa230e3fa1b1b5 -> found doctrine/common[dev-remove-int-cast, 2.1.3, ..., 2.13.x-dev, 3.0.0, ..., 3.5.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
    - drupal/core[8.0.0-beta7, ..., 8.0.0-beta12] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.0.0, ..., 5.3.4] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[8.0.0-beta13, ..., 8.0.0-beta15] require guzzlehttp/guzzle dev-master#1879fbe853b0c64d109e369c7aeff09849e62d1e -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[dev-improve-checks-for-http-2, dev-test, v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v2.0.0, ..., v2.8.8, v3.0.0, ..., v3.8.1, 4.0.0-rc.1, ..., 4.x-dev, 5.0.0, ..., 5.3.x-dev, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev, 7.0.0-beta.1, ..., 7.9.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
    - drupal/core[8.0.0-beta16, ..., 8.1.6] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.1 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core 8.1.7 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.2 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[8.1.8, ..., 8.7.14] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.2.1 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.1, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[8.8.0-beta1, ..., 8.9.10] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.3 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.20] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.1.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/core[9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.3.13] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5.2 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.2, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[9.0.10, ..., 9.0.14] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - drupal/core[9.2.20, ..., 9.3.15] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5.6 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.6, 6.5.7, 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[9.2.21, ..., 9.3.16] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5.7 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.7, 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - drupal/core[9.3.17, ..., 9.3.22] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5.8 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (~7.7.0).
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/vefl ^3.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/vefl[3.0.0].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 requires drupal/core 10.1.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.2 requires drupal/core 10.1.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.3 requires drupal/core 10.1.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.4 requires drupal/core 10.1.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.5 requires drupal/core 10.1.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0 requires drupal/core 10.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/vefl 3.0.0 requires drupal/core ^8 || ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.5.11].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.7.0-beta1, ..., 8.9.20, 9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.5.11, 10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-rc1 requires drupal/core 10.1.0-rc1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0-rc1].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].

    Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

I intentionally set the require for guzzle to ~7.7.0 but as you can see, it fails.  When I set it back to 6.5:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.0.11] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.5.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.5).
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-beta1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.5.1 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.5).
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.1.0-rc1, ..., 10.1.5] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.7.0, 7.7.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.5).
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

[root@ip-172-31-13-94 demo9]# **composer update -W**

```
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.0.11] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.5.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.5).
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-beta1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.5.1 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.5).
    - drupal/core-recommended[10.1.0-rc1, ..., 10.1.5] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~7.7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.7.0, 7.7.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^6.5).
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].
```

How in the world do I get past this?

I just completed the upgrade of an almost identical site in which the commands above worked fine.

```
- Upgrading guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.5.8 => 7.7.1)

  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.3 => 2.0.1)

  - Upgrading guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.9.1 => 2.5.1)
```

How do I get around these Catch-22s?  In following the guidelines here, here appears to be no way to upgrade guzzle to the version I need to upgrade: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site

These are my composer.json requires:

```
"require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.279",
    "ckeditor/liststyle": "4.8.0",
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.0",
    "drupal/adva": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/advancedqueue": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/backup_migrate": "^5.0@RC",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0",
    "drupal/book_blocks": "^1.6",
    "drupal/ckeditor5_font": "^1.1@beta",
    "drupal/ckeditor5_paste_filter": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/ckeditor_config": "^3.0",
    "drupal/ckeditor_find": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/ckeditor_font": "^1.2",
    "drupal/ckeditor_indentblock": "1.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/ckeditor_liststyle": "1.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/colorbutton": "^1.2",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
    "drupal/custom_book_block": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/d8w3css": "^2.0",
    "drupal/devel": "^5.1",
    "drupal/devel_kint_extras": "^1.1",
    "drupal/devel_php": "^1.3",
    "drupal/disable_messages": "^2.1",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.2",
    "drupal/editor_file": "^1.5",
    "drupal/email_confirmer": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.2",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.5",
    "drupal/entity_print": "^2.11",
    "drupal/entity_reference_facet_link": "^2.0",
    "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.9",
    "drupal/eva": "^3.0",
    "drupal/extlink": "^1.6",
    "drupal/facets": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.1",
    "drupal/flag": "^4.0@beta",
    "drupal/flexible_permissions": "^1.1",
    "drupal/group": "^2.2",
    "drupal/highlight": "^1.0",
    "drupal/jquery_ui": "^1.6",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^2.0",
    "drupal/key_auth": "^2.1",
    "drupal/libraries": "^4.0",
    "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.3",
    "drupal/media_migration": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.2",
    "drupal/message": "^1.2",
    "drupal/message_notify": "^1.2",
    "drupal/message_subscribe": "^1.1",
    "drupal/migrate_conditions": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/migrate_devel": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/migrate_plus": "^6.0",
    "drupal/migrate_tools": "^6.0",
    "drupal/migrate_upgrade": "^4.0",
    "drupal/mimemail": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/nbsp": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/override_node_options": "^2.6",
    "drupal/panelbutton": "^1.3",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "1.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/paragraphs_access": "^2.0@RC",
    "drupal/paragraphs_collapsible": "^1.2",
    "drupal/paragraphs_jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.6",
    "drupal/pdf_api": "2.x-dev@dev",
    "drupal/phpmailer_smtp": "^2.0",
    "drupal/printable": "^3.0",
    "drupal/queue_ui": "^3.1",
    "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.14",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.7",
    "drupal/restrict_ip": "^4.0@beta",
    "drupal/restui": "^1.21",
    "drupal/s3fs": "^3.1",
    "drupal/scheduled_publish": "^3.9",
    "drupal/scheduler": "^1.3",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.19",
    "drupal/search_api_attachments": "^9.0",
    "drupal/search_api_location": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/search_api_solr": "^4.1",
    "drupal/search_api_spellcheck": "^4.0",
    "drupal/simple_popup_blocks": "^3.1",
    "drupal/simplenews": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/site_settings": "^1.19",
    "drupal/smtp": "^1.0",
    "drupal/token": "^1.9",
    "drupal/token_filter": "^2.0",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/upgrade_rector": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/upgrade_status": "^4.0",
    "drupal/user_permission_condition": "^1.1",
    "drupal/userprotect": "^1.1",
    "drupal/variationcache": "^1.0",
    "drupal/vefl": "^3.0",
    "drupal/views_accordion": "^2.0.1",
    "drupal/views_block_filter_block": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.3",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.3",
    "drush/drush": "^10",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.13",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "^0.12.4",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386": "^0.12.4",
    "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "^2.5",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.5",
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "~6"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
```

**Update:**

I added guzzle to the composer command and removed vefl and highlight:

```
 Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-beta2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-beta1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-rc1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.0.11 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 10.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/core-dev[9.2.0-beta3, ..., 9.2.21] require fabpot/goutte ^3.3 -> satisfiable by fabpot/goutte[v3.3.0, v3.3.1].
    - symfony/browser-kit[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., v4.4.8] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - fabpot/goutte v3.3.0 require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.14) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - fabpot/goutte v3.3.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.5).
    - drupal/core-dev[9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.0.14] require symfony/browser-kit ^4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/browser-kit[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., v4.4.44].
    - drupal/core-dev[9.3.0-beta2, ..., 9.5.11] require symfony/var-dumper ^5.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.4.0-BETA1, ..., v5.4.29].
    - drupal/core-dev 9.3.0-beta1 requires symfony/var-dumper ^5.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.3.0-BETA1, ..., v5.4.29].
    - drupal/core-dev[9.1.0-beta1, ..., 9.2.0-beta2] require symfony/var-dumper ^5.1.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v5.1.2, ..., v5.4.29].
    - symfony/http-kernel[v6.1.0-BETA1, ..., v6.1.12] conflict with symfony/browser-kit v4.4.44.
    - symfony/http-kernel[v6.1.0-BETA1, ..., v6.1.12] conflict with symfony/browser-kit v4.4.25.
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: symfony/var-dumper[v3.4.0-BETA1, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., v4.4.47, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., v5.4.29, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., v6.4.0-BETA2, v7.0.0-BETA1, v7.0.0-BETA2].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-beta1 requires symfony/http-kernel ~v6.1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v6.1.4, ..., v6.1.12].
    - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-beta1 requires symfony/var-dumper ~v6.1.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v6.1.3, ..., v6.1.11].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-dev ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-dev[9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.5.11].
```

These two lines are confusing:

```
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.5].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-dev ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-dev[9.0.0-beta1, ..., 9.5.11].
```

Comment: Show the composer.json file. Did you actually try including the Guzzle upgrade in your first command?

Comment: I think this is your culprit ‘drupal/vefl 3.0.0 requires drupal/core ^8 || ^9’

Comment: I added my composer.json requires to the post.  If you mean adding the guzzle upgrade to the actual composer command, no I did not.  I updated the composer.json file for  guzzle require ~7.7 and 7.5 and neither worked.

I added guzzle to the composer command and removed vefl.  Still will not update.  I posted results in "update" to original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I finally got the site to upgrade:

Removed these patched modules:

"drupal/highlight": "^1.0",

"drupal/vefl": "^3.0",

"drupal/vefl": {
                "Drupal 10 support": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-03-17/vefl-drupal10-compatibility.patch"
            },

"drupal/highlight": {
                "Automated Drupal 10 compatibility fixes": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-06-15/highlight.1.x-dev.rector.patch"
            }

Added DEV into the mix:

**composer require 'drupal/core-dev:^10' 'guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.5' 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update --dev**

**composer require 'drush/drush:^12' --no-update**

**composer update -W**

Those modules were patched using cweagans/composer-patches and had ^10 in their info.yml files.  Anyway, made it to 10.1.5.